# Persisting Silent File Corruption Through Mirrored Backup

Tags: filesystems, backup

I have over two terabytes of flac files and I mirror those files to another drive using RoboCopy.

I was wondering about the following scenario.

The drive storing the files begins to fail and several of sectors where the flac data is written become corrupt.

If RoboCopy attempted to copy these corrupt files what would happen?

Do all modern operating systems recognize this situation and prevent the copy from occurring?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need a filesystem that actively detects and/or prevents silent data corruption such as [ZFS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/zfsover-2/index.html) or [Btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).